# When you cook spaghetti, do you add olive oil to the boiling water?

Tags: oil, boiling, olive, spaghetti

Many people (at least in Germany) think that Italians add olive oil to the boiling water for spaghetti. However, Italians tend to tell the opposite (from my experience).

So, can you please state objective reasons for or against adding olive oil to the boiling water for spaghetti?

Comment: related, if not a duplicate: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-can-i-keep-pasta-from-sticking-to-itself and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/pasta-simmering-water-or-rolling-boil

Comment: Different experiences of germans vs italian might have to do with germans being fond of dried egg pasta. Maybe it behaves differently?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, it is true that we don't add oil to the boiling water. I'm not aware of any good reason to waste extra-virgin olive oil that way! Some oil is always added at the end, over the sauce, when the pasta is already in the plate! It has to be raw, so that it retains its fruit nuances and texture.

If you are doing cold pasta salad and want to avoid sticky pasta, adding oil in advance won't help. You have instead to wash pasta under cold water to wash the starch away (you can put the pasta in the colander directly under the running cold tap).

Comment: Is adding a bit of salt to the water good practice, however? I have heard this before, but am not too sure on the convetion/practicality.

Comment: @Noldorin: you have always to add salt to the water, when it started boiling, and **before** adding pasta. Pasta always had to be cooked in salted water. The correct ratio is "dieci, cento, mille" (ten, one hundred, one thousand): 10 g of salt, 100 g of pasta, 1 liter of water.

Comment: @Lorenzo: Good, this is pretty much what I've always done, but thanks for confirming it! Easy way to remember too, though I doubt I'll be measuring anything out.

Comment: @Noldorin: neither I actually measure salt or water, but the rule is useful for pasta newbies and of course when you have to cook huge quantities at once.

Comment: I am so glad this myth has been debunked. I have tried it a few times but found that it made no difference. The same applies to adding the oil after you've thrown away the water. // Washing the starch away with water sounds like agood idea (with warm water might be a better idea if you want to keep the pasta warm?): I wash my rice with hot water if it is stoo slimey, either because I had it boil too long or because it was the last bit in the carton/bag with lots of powdery stuff.

Comment: With regard to adding oil afterwards, I find butter (or even a decent flavoured substitute) gives a much nicer flavour.  Personal opinion of course.

Comment: I believe when cooking pasta in commercial quantities (in a huge cauldron of a pot, cooking many, many kilos at a time) oil is still used (to stop the pasta from sticking together under its own weight) but in that case it's more likely to be a cheap vegetable oil than an extra virgin olive oil. I have no references to prove this though.

Answer (score 25):

Alton Brown covered this on an episode of Good Eats.  There is a legitimate reason, and it has nothing to do with sticking; it's an anti-foaming agent, so you don't have to stir as much to keep down the foam you'll sometimes get.

Any oil will work, it doesn't  have to be the good stuff.

Comment: I would still advice against it. Oil in hot water does strange things, not only to foam, but to the pasta itself. After all, no one does that in Italy...

Comment: @lorenzo : I agree.  It's better without oil, I was just trying to explain why it's done, not advocate for it.  Rinsing the pasta to remove the loose starch should have the same effect, but I'd only recommend it for when you're planning an oil based sauce and don't need the starch to bind the sauce to the pasta.

Comment: but the only time you have to avoid the stickiness is cold pasta salad, and the best way to wash away the starch is actually washing it under cold water.

Comment: I agree with Lorenzo: washing the pasta is a good way to stop over-foaming; however I disagree with him/her in that the oil will not do anything strange, at least in the sense that it will be harmful to the pasta.  A little (cheap vegetable) oil will help prevent over-foaming.  The oil sits on top of the water and rarely comes into contact with the pasta long enough for the pasta to absorb it.

Answer (score 3):

Using it anti-stick apparently does NOT work. (Just use a large enough pan and stir somewhere during the start of boiling).

Adding oil will also reduce flavor-uptake from any sauce.

Answer (score 2):

I've never put oil on spaghetti's water and i've never seen anyone doing it here in Italy.
To keep your spaghetti out of trouble (sticking), just have the patience to mix them on the water (just for the first couple of minutes).

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason that I have heard is to help prevent the pasta from sticking together (and maybe to add a little flavor).  This is unnecessary on both points, however.

Spaghetti is one of those foods that should be served right away.  If it is, you will rarely have a sticky mess.  If you do let it sit until it sticks, the pasta can be rinsed to loosen it up.

Adding oil to the water does not add much flavor or anti-sticking power.  Most of it will be discarded with the water, and what is left may help prevent the pasta from taking up the flavor of the sauce.

Update:  Joe's answer about oil being an anti-foaming agent is a great tip!

Answer (score 1):

I never used to use oil in the water when I was cooking spagetti but I found that it tended to stick together in a pick clump that was hard and difficult to eat.

I was advised to start using oil in my water and I have not looked back since. It keeps the spaghetti separate and therefore an overall better eating experience.

As for oil, it does not have to be olive oil, it can be any kind of oil...or at least that is what I have found!

Comment: I'm not sure how much the oil has to do with the spaghetti being kept separate.  I think there might be other factors at play here.  See some of the questions I linked in a comment at the top for more details.

Comment: Yeah, the pasta is under the water surface, and the oil all floats to the top. What keeps the pasta from sticking is *stirring*.

Comment: I'm sure how much the oil has to do with the spaghetti staying separate: nothing whatsoever.

Comment: @roux, I was trying to be polite.

Answer (score 1):

I have always been told that adding fat to the pasta water coats the pasta in the fat, which prevents the pasta from absorbing the sauce. I have tried it a couple of times. The results weren’t disastrous (it was edible), but the pasta did indeed seem to shy away from the sauce, so I don’t do it any more.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, all else being equal, Italian style water-boiled pasta tastes bland. But I have grown eating pasta and rice boiled with virgin olive oil, so I am certainly biased.

Even after washing with cold water to use for salads as Lorenzo advises, I can tell the difference.

Why, I ain't sure, but I think it might be due to the oil interacting with the starch.

I have also noticed less sticking, but that's not the main reason for me to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I cook pasta without olive oil. But due to timing differences (I arrive home time X, my wife Y, and the kids Z). To make sure the pasta doesn't stick, and can be prepared beforehand, I cook it in salted and buttered water for taste. I stir it continuously to avoid sticking, but after draining the water, I add some EVOO to the pasta as it cools and stir it. I find that hot pasta tends to stick as it cools.

Answer (score 0):

In Italy we indeed put a bit of oil in the boiling water, but ONLY in case of fresh homemade pasta, not in the DRY one that you buy in the supermarket.

In case of fresh pasta, we use flour as anti-sticky, but when put in the water flour doesn't work anymore and a bit of oil helps.

In case of dry pasta is not needed anymore because the causes of stickiness are different.

Beware that you should stir the pasta in the boiling water at least when you put it in and every 2 minutes. Anyway, stirring to much the fresh pasta can break it (since has different consistence and "physical properties").

Enjoy your pasta!

Answer (score -1):

The "experts" are not always right. A little oil keeps the pasta from sticking together and improves texture and flavor.

Answer (score -4):

Ok people here you have it. Finally the answer to should there be oil in the pasta. When my family and friends hear I am putting together my macaroni salad everyone asks me to make enough for them to take some home. This tells me what i am doing is the right way. Everyone loves my pasta. This makes me an expert. Therefore in my expert opinion YES you put a small amount of oil in the water to boil pasta. Rapid boil the water add salt and oil. The oil will mix with the rapidly boiling water and not sit on top as some may seem to think. Cook till desired texture. Then remove and drain and rinse in cold water.This stops the cooking process. Leaving the pasta in warm water ends up over cooking the pasta. Some think the oil does not allow your sauce to stay on the pasta. A good rinse resolves that myth. The oil helps with boil overs sticking and clumping and you wont have to stand there and stir, you can go on and cut your veggies or open your wine. Now you know the answer.

Comment: I don't think oil does any of the things you think it does except maybe help prevent boil overs, and those can be avoided with a simple stir now and then and a heat adjustment.