# My water is boiling too fast

Tags: boiling, water, pot

Every time I try to boil a pot of water to make spaghetti, I leave the kitchen to go do something else (I am very busy lol). Sometimes I come back to find the pot boiling over and a mess on my stove! Is there some way I can make the water boil more slowly so I have more time to run my errands?

Comment: Do you just leave it on high?

Comment: A simmermat possibly, to defuse the heat?

Comment: When you say "errands", you aren't actually leaving the house, are you? That could be really dangerous, if say the water boils over, extinguishes the flame, and fills your house with gas.

Comment: Silly suggestion: give me your stove, and you can have mine. It takes *forever* to boil water. ;)

Comment: @Eric - spaghetti takes about 9 minutes.  Instead of leaving the kitchen, have a glass of water and take a second to breathe while watching your pot.  Make whatever sauce is going on your spaghetti.  Multi-task by doing a few dishes.  In other words - *stay in the kitchen*.

Comment: i second @justkt - there are *always* some kind of errands in the kitchen at my house that I can do while I have "down time" during meals - pantry inventory (what's getting old?) is a big one, but most often I just wash dishes, empty the drainboard, or prep the rest of the meal.  i also listen to the Cooking Issues or Splendid Table podcasts while i'm in the kitchen so i'm never "bored" :)

Comment: This doesn't seem much like a cooking question. The problem doesn't seem to be with the cooking... it's with the "errands".

Comment: You water is boiling?  Major Ouchies!  (SCNR)

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how a pot of plain water is "boiling over" and making a "mess." I can see that a really rolling boil in a too-small pot would splash out some--maybe even a lot--but "a mess?" Maybe it's just me and the things I've spilled that have made REAL messes, but spilled water just doesn't earn that name to me.

Comment: @bikeboy - if you're leaving the lid on (see my answer below), then the mess comes in the form of lots of gluten-caused bubbles

Comment: @zanlok: I read the OP as being BEFORE the pasta went in. "I go to boil water..." and, "make the water boil more slowly." With no mention of adding pasta, I figured we hadn't gotten to that point. Could be wrong, though.

Comment: @bb - ha, yes, now I see that. indeed, then, on the why is it a "mess". haha. if anything, how water would help to clean my perpetually messy rangetop :)

Answer (score 10):

Turn the temperature down - Once the pot reaches boil, it takes a lot less energy to keep it boiling, turning the temperature down it will keep it from boiling quite so violently.

Don't overfill your pot - Makes sure you are using a pot large enough to handle all the water and pasta

A teaspoon of oil will also help - This helps keep the water from building the bubbles causing it to foam over.  [When you cook spaghetti, do you add olive oil to the boiling water?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/when-you-cook-spaghetti-do-you-add-olive-oil-to-the-boiling-water)

Answer (score 7):

Use a kettle?  When boiling water for pasta, I just boil it in the kettle and pour into the pan.  Has the benefit I can just start it boiling and forget about it until I need it

Answer (score 4):

Use a small kitchen timer. Set it for the time takes your pot of water to boil, and put it in your pocket or on lanyard. Then "errand away" until it beeps

Nice timers at http://www.dealextreme.com/products.dx/category.1013~search.timer from credit card to apple sized

This works for anything of course, not just boiling water. You can bake cookies, and still "errand away" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add some salt and a little olive oil when putting the water to boil. As it will make the water more dense it will boil a little harder than regular water. The olive oil is also good to prevent the pasta from getting stuck to the pot and the salt you need it dissolved so it can be absorbed by the pasta.

Comment: The amount of salt used in this application would not likely be enough to raise the boiling point more than one farenheit degree. It's not bad advice, but it won't help with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could always boil the water in the oven if you're worried about spillover. This will allow you to use a bigger pot as well and have more precise control over the temperature.

Comment: Boiling water in an oven is massively, massively inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the [answer](http://www.meninaprons.net/2006/08/how_to_avoid_boil_over_when_co.html) is very simple: **leave the lid OFF**.

There's a lot of other answers here that may be missing a beginner's bad approach to boiling noodles. We often use a lid to decrease time to get to boiling, but once you add the dried pasta and fluff it to keep it from sticking together, don't return the lid back onto the pot.

When cooking pasta, you should actually pay attention and leave on high for a minute (or so, depends on your rangetop) until boiling resumes, and then lower the heat. After that, your attention can wane until the final timer goes off - not that you should leave the house, haha.

Some recipes actually call for turning the heat off at a point in the process to preparing noodles, similar to my favorite method of cooking corn on the cob, hard-boiled eggs, or even when boiling potatoes for mashed potatoes. As an aside, though turning the heat off isn't my norm in practice, it's a great way to more precisely time perfectly "al dente" noodles (or more precisely reaching any desired texture, for that matter). Or, if you insist on having a lid on the pot for whatever reason, cant it so the steam can escape.

Leaving the lid on, with high heat, can actually cause other of starchy and/or "glutenous" things to boil over, such as oatmeal.