# Why does my rice cooker's steam hole always clog?

Tags: equipment, rice, rice-cooker

The lid on my rice cooker has a small steam hole that gets clogged from bubbles forming and the quinoa gets stuck and then the whole thing boils over and makes a mess. Am I doing something wrong? How do I keep it from doing this?

Note: this was taken from [a deleted answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/36303/1672) to [How do I keep the rice cooker from boiling over?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/9857/1672) I don't actually have a rice cooker, so I can't provide extra details; answers about all potential causes and fixes are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

If the foam from your rice cooker is reaching all the way to the lid, it may be over-filled. At least for very small grains, like quinoa, you may need to prepare it in smaller batches so that it can't be carried up to the lid.

Quinoa also has a coating of saponins on the outside of the grain. These soap-like chemicals can cause water to foam and also impart a soapy taste, they should always be washed off before cooking.

In general, adding a few drops of oil to the surface of the cooking water can help to reduce the amount of foam produced.