# How do I avoid rice cookers emitting strange goo on my counter?

Tags: rice, rice-cooker

With my rice cooker, I always have to put a paper towel underneath it before I start it, because it tends to make a mess. It creates piles of white watery starch goo. I don't really know how else to describe it other than the title. It's not really overflowing, since it occurs even when the rice cooker only has a small amount of rice in it - it looks like it's condensing from the air or something.

I usually just measure in rice and water, then turn it on and leave. Is this a common problem? Am I doing something wrong in the cooking process? Perhaps I have a bad rice cooker or cheap rice? What are some good rice cookers and/or cooking methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep the rice cooker from boiling over?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9857/how-do-i-keep-the-rice-cooker-from-boiling-over)

Comment: I would keep the title the old way, just because it would help people find the question with Google search (as it's what I was looking up)

Comment: Also, it's not really overflowing, just a weird substance builds up from nowhere. It's not as if the liquid level rises over the top, at least from what I can see.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Unfortunately I think vulgar language isn't welcome here, see our Code of Conduct https://cooking.stackexchange.com/conduct, particularly the harassment section. Otherwise we'd already have plenty of questions with explicit phrasing concerning topics such as bursting hot dogs :)

Comment: Have you checked your cooker's instructions? When it comes to white rice, mine recommends thoroughly rinsing it at least 2-3 times to avoid it foaming all over the place. Does this happen when you use other rice types, such as brown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some rice cookers have a vent on the side, and there's a little cup with it that clips in there to catch the starchy moisture that might escape during cooking.

If your rice cooker came with a small plastic cup (I say 'cup' as it's a container, but it's usually pretty flat so it doesn't stick out very far) that you couldn't figure out what it was for, this is likely your problem.  It usually attaches near the hinge.

Not all rice cookers have them, though.  My 10 cup does, but the little 2 cup that I got at a thrift store doesn't.  (it vents from the top, and the lid lifts off completely)

Comment: I've used a piece of paper towel over the vent successfully before.

Answer (score 1):

Bad rice cooker, I doubt the problem could possibly be the rice.  Thrift stores are full of them, just get another.  Although maybe you could be contributing to the problem by filling your rice cooker to the brim?

Comment: I probably will just get another rice cooker then. I usually only fill it about half way.

Comment: Then your cooker probably has a lid that doesn't fit tightly enough.

Comment: It pays to get a good one. Japanese, Panasonic or Zojirushi. with fuzzy logic and slow cook times you can make a lot more than just rice. Even cakes! The cheap American ones are what they are, cheap white, and possibly brown cookers. The deasign seems to be based off the slow cookers of old, and that doesn't handle steam right when cooking rice.

Comment: Oh yes.  I'd head to the nearest Asian grocery store to get a better one for sure..